# Creating a gnome desktop file with custom command

Tags: gnome, command-line

Via terminal I can launch application as s particular groupid:

```
sudo sg - nonet nonetmath
```

where **nonet** is the group name & **nonetmath** is the binary in /bin...
Now I want to create a .desktop file for ease of access

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Mathe
Exec=sudo sg - nonet nonetmath
Icon=<iconpath>
Categories=Education;
```

but this isn't not working...the system is configured such that sudo dont prompt for pswd this was done by editing

```
sudo visudo
```

any help here

Comment: Is your `.desktop` file executable? They have to be.

Comment: There also is a `[` missing in the first line of your file. I'm guessing it's a typo that happened while posting here, but I thought I better mention it ;-)

Comment: Thnx, it was a typo while posting here. Problem isn't yet solved guys? I can perfectly run command in terminal why not via .desktop file?

Comment: Did you check if the file is executable? You should also use `desktop-file-validate` on your file to check if it has any errors.

Comment: does is work now?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the same problem, but I can never make my .desktop files or launchers work with `sudo`. I click on them and nothing happens. When I change it to `gksudo`, however, they work fine.

Comment: This is right. `sudo` is a terminal program, it doesn't display a dialog. You need to use `gksudo` or `pkexec`